# Create strong key for AES-256 from big keyfile

Tags: encryption, aes

I was wondering how to create a strong key for AES-256 from the contents of a big file (25MB to 5GB). in other words, the big file acts as some kind of key-file which is transformed into a short key for aes. the method to generate the key should be fast for big files, deterministic and work with any kind of file (even ones with patterns, or simple text files). I found that using md5 to derive this key is quite slow and its security is not needed, as I don't have to prevent file tampering. I just want to create a secure key with little collisions. I am aware that using the file does not add anymore security than the key itself.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a large file for this? You could take the sha256 sum of the first 1MB and run it through PBKDF2.

Comment: i also want to confirm that the user has the big file installed on his machine, but since this file never goes public there is no need to prevent forging

Comment: Unless you have a really fast disk (SSD raid or something like that) reading the file takes much longer than calculating the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `md5sum` or `sha256sum` to get a hash of the large file. The performance won't be much worse than simply reading the whole file from disk.

If you really need speed, then you could use [Adler-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32), but note that this is trivial to forge, and cannot be used to create a strong key for AES.